# XMonad Logs | How to check if a key binding did fire or not?

Tags: xmonad

I am using Xmonad for a while and it is working fine but some of the key bindings are not working and I want to see the log to diagnose the problem. BUT I am not able to find the log files for this? Any idea where these are located?

*UPDATE :* 
*I have a binding like this :*

```
, ((myModMask, xK_l), spawn "scrot -s 'Selected_%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/screenshots/'")
```

*But the key combination does not produce anything, and I am not able to figure out if the command is spawned or not. copy pasting on terminal works but through key combination it does not....How should I diagnose this?*

```
Linux archlinux 5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 16 11:29:43 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks

Comment: They usually just go out to stdout / stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with scrot itself. Details :

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Screen_capture#scrot

Note: In some window managers (dwmAUR, xmonad and possibly others) scrot -s does not work properly when running via window manager's keyboard shortcut, this can be worked around by prepending scrot invocation with a short pause sleep 0.2; scrot -s.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://github.com/naelstrof/maim